# Can i put these filter flags in an array?

Tags: php

```
$ipAdd=$_POST['ip'];
if (filter_var($ipAdd, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE) === false) { 
    echo "Invalid IP Address";   
}
else {
    echo 'Your IP is: '.$ipAdd;
}
```

Comment: no. filter_var expects a single value, not an array. you can pre-calculate the filter mask and store that value in a variable. e.g. `$foo = a|b|c; filter_var(..., $foo)`.

Comment: i mean can i put these 3 flags in an array, not to use "  |  " FILTER_FLAG_IPV4|FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE|FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE

Comment: you can put anything you want in an array, you just can't pass that array to filter_var.

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_GET,'numri', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options"=>array("min_range"=>5, "max_range"=>20)));      we have array options here specified as third parameter of filter_input,,so i am asking can we do this to the first example

Comment: No. Read what @MarcB wrote. Also, from http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php : `mixed filter_var ( mixed $variable [, int $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT [, mixed $options ]] )`, this means it can only take an Integer value, not an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Options can be passed as an array as you described in the comments, yet not exactly like you may want. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php for the proper format.

```
$options = array(
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE
);
$ipAdd = isset($_POST['ip'])?$_POST['ip']:"";
if(filter_var($ipAdd, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, $options) === false){
    echo "Invalid IP Address";   
} else {
    echo 'Your IP is: '.$ipAdd;
}
```

You have to use the pipes (`|`) since they are Bitwise Operators. The filter flags equate to a binary value.